# How to define a variable for all Gradle subprojects using Gradle Kotlin DSL

Tags: kotlin, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I am following [this](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/writing_build_scripts.html) guide.

The guide reads: *Extra properties on a project are visible from its subprojects*.
This does not seem to work for me, as the following does not work:

In `build.gradle.kts` I have:

```
val ktorVersion by extra("1.3.2")
```

In `subproject/build.gradle.kts` I have:

```
dependencies {
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktorVersion")
}
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In the project level `build.gradle.kts`:

```
val ktorVersion by extra { "1.3.2" }
```

In the `subproject/build.gradle.kts`:

```
val ktorVersion: String by rootProject.extra

dependencies {  
   implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktorVersion")
}
```

For more info: [Gradle docs on Extra properties](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/kotlin_dsl.html#extra_properties)

Comment: I don't understand. Why would the documentation say: "Extra properties on a project are visible", if that's not the case?

Comment: Not really what I wanted, but close enough

Comment: this looks ugly, because you declare variable two times...

Answer (score 13):

Also, you may define the versions in an object inside the `buildSrc` [project](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/organizing_gradle_projects.html#sec:build_sources). `buildSrc` is a special project in Gradle, all declarations from it are visible across all Gradle projects (except `settings.gradle.kts`). So you may have

buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/myPackage/Versions.kt

```
object Versions {
  const val ktorVersion = "1.2.3"
}
```

And then use it from any your `build.gradle` (.kts) files

```
import myPackage.Versions.ktorVersion

dependencies {
  implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktorVersion")
}
```

UPD: currently recommended way to solve this problem is to use https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/platforms.html

```
dependencies {
    implementation(libs.groovy.core)
    implementation(libs.groovy.json)
    implementation(libs.groovy.nio)
}
```

Comment: This is cleaner. The other option is fugly.

Comment: This is cleaner since we don't have to redeclare `ktorVersion` on sub-projects.

Comment: Cleaner but might be slower because update of ANY version in buildSrc/src/main/kotlin/myPackage/Versions.kt will cause gradle to recompile build scripts. See https://melix.github.io/blog/2021/03/version-catalogs.html

Answer (score 1):

root build.gradle.kts

```
buildscript {
    val ktorVersion by extra("1.2.3")
    //OR
    //extra.set("ktorVersion", "1.2.3")
}
```

project build.gradle.kts

```
dependencies {
    val ktorVersion : String by rootProject.extra
    implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:$ktorVersion")
    //OR
    //implementation("io.ktor:ktor-server-core:${rootProject.extra.get("ktorVersion")}
}
```

From [here](https://medium.com/grandcentrix/a-deeper-look-into-gradles-kotlin-dsl-3498ecf80026#e530)